# Using rake notes with .html.erb files in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting started with Rails (3.2.3), and have recently discovered the rake notes feature.

This is working fine for .rb files, with comments like this:

```
     # TODO ...
```

According to the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#notes) it also works for .erb files.  I have tried using it in the .html.erb view files like this:

```
    <!-- TODO ... -->
```

But this doesn't work.  Should it?  Any ideas on what might be going wrong?

Appreciate your help!

Comment: +1 for having never heard of this feature :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do it like this:

```
<% #TODO ... %>
```

`rake notes` only detects Ruby comments, so just stick a Ruby comment into your Erb views and you're good to go.

Comment: Aaah.  Got it.  I had tried <%= #TODO ...%>.  Many thanks.  Can you give any insight on the meaning of the '=' (i.e. <%= ... %> vs. <% ... %>?

Answer (score 0):

When I used <% and # with a space in between it breaks other HTML elements around the code in Rails version 2.3. However, you should be able to use <%# (without space) and it is the proper way to have comments in erb, check this out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ERuby

Also

"*Aaah. Got it. I had tried <%= #TODO ...%>. Many thanks. Can you give any insight on the meaning of the '=' (i.e. <%= ... %> vs. <% ... %>? – Derek Hill Jun 30 at 23:25*"

**In reply to the above question:**

Content between <%=..%> is interpreted and executed as Ruby code and the result of the execution is converted into string and printed on the output in place of <%=..%>. 
Whereas, content between <%..%> is interpreted and executed as Ruby code with no result displayed on the output.

Answer (score 0):

TextMate (for Mac) include TODO bundle that detects HTML comments () among others languages